# How do I make an element follow the mouse?

Tags: javascript, css

I wanted to make a div follow mouse so I added this code:

```js
const move = document.getElementById("move");

document.body.onpointermove = event => {
    const { clientX, clientY } = event;

    move.animate({
        left: `${clientX}px`,
        top: `${clientY}px`
    
    }, {duration: 1000, fill: "forwards"})

}
```

```css
#move{
    background: linear-gradient(
        to right,
        #ff8e8e,
        #ff006a
    ) ;
    height: 300px;
    aspect-ratio: 1;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div id="move"></div>
```

At first when I inspected the site in my browser the JS was changing left and top value as I was moving my mouse but it wasn't moving. Because of this, I added this into css `position: fixed;`. The div started following my mouse but only if it was over it. I wanted the div to always follow the mouse but I don't know how to do it.

I hope that somebody will help me with this.

Comment: instead of `document.body` use `window`, so it will be `window.onpointermove` (this can be a first solution) ... but the real reason, definitely is in CSS rather in JS, because the body element should gain more space so the event can be fired (the box #move is nested inside body in the markup and this is why is only moving when hovered the box, but technically with devtools you will see that body has little space in reality)

Comment: I took the liberty of renaming and reformatting your question a bit for clarity.  Good job on providing a minimal example, when people do this it makes it easy to help 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is simply caused by the fact the body element now has a height of 0 (since setting `position: fixed` on the div removed it from normal flow and the body no longer reserves space for it). Your cursor is technically outside the body when you move it around the page, so it doesn't fire the `pointermove event`. But when the cursor is inside the div, which is itself a descendant of the body, it counts as being inside the body.

You could fix this by attaching the event to the window instead of the body, or by making sure the html and body elements have a minimum height.

```js
const move = document.getElementById("move");

document.body.onpointermove = event => {
    const { clientX, clientY } = event;

    move.animate({
        left: `${clientX}px`,
        top: `${clientY}px`
    
    }, {duration: 1000, fill: "forwards"})

}
```

```css
html { height: 100%; }
body { min-height: 100%; }

#move{
    background: linear-gradient(
        to right,
        #ff8e8e,
        #ff006a
    ) ;
    height: 300px;
    aspect-ratio: 1;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div id="move"></div>
```

Comment: PS: The reason a scrollbar appear is because the body has a default margin so it doesn't quite fit in the HTML. You could fix this by reducing the min-height of the body a bit to account for that margin, something like `min-height: 90%` or `min-height: calc(100% - 2em)`.